# What does this partial differential equation mean and how to solve it?

Tags: calculus, differential

Let $u = \frac{yz}{x},   v = \frac{zx}{y}, w = \frac{xy}{z}$ , find:

$$\frac{\partial (u,v,w)}{\partial (x,y,z)}.$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Ish Where have you encountered this question?

Comment: I got a question paper with this question.. Thank for the link for mathjax tutorial

Comment: I haven't tried anything....I don't know what to calculate.. I am familiar with the partial derivatives concept but I don't know how to read this notation.. Can u pls help!!??

Comment: You are supposed to calculate the Jacobi matrix of the function f = (u, v, w).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have seen notation like this, it refers to the following matrix:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial(u,v,w)}{\partial(x,y,z)} \;=\;
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

This is known as the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). Note that the determinant of a Jacobian matrix frequently shows up when making a change of variables in a multidimensional integral.

Comment: Thanks John Barber for your answer... This really helps a lot!!

Comment: If you feel that this response has adequately answered your question, you can "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark.